# Stream API Java 8 Parallel Processing

Tags: parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 sets

`phraseSet` contains "eiffel tower", "tokyo tower"

`wordSet` contains words like "eiffel" , "tower"

How do I use Java 8 parallel stream to process logic like:
1. for each item in `phraseSet`, tokenize it, see if all tokens exist in `wordSet`, if so add that item to a new set called `resultSet`.
In this example, `resultSet` would contain "eiffel tower"

It's easy to do if i do using traditional for loop, but i am confused when attempting it using parallel stream, which i hope is faster too since it's processed in parallel.

Comment: Parallel processing does not, always, mean faster.

Comment: in this case should be faster right, just curious in which scenario is it slower ?

Comment: There is overhead of creating parallel processing and combining the result. You will start seeing performance benefit only when input set is sufficiently large (thousands, if not millions) and/or each single element processing takes sufficiently long time (seconds, if not minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `filter` and an `allMatch` would be sufficient:

```
Set<String> phrases = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("eifel tower", "tokyo tower"));
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("eifel", "tower"));
Pattern delimiter = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

Set<String> resultSet = phrases.parallelStream().filter(
    phrase -> delimiter.splitAsStream(phrase).allMatch(words::contains)
).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Good answer, but I’d move the `Pattern.compile("\\s+")` step out of the stream, to avoid repeating it for every element. Also mind that `Set.of` is Java 9 and the OP might not be aware of it.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for the feedback. Improvements included now.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be

```
Set<String> resultSet = phraseSet.stream()
    .filter(s -> wordSet.containsAll(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+"))))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

You may turn this to parallel processing by replacing `stream()` with `parallelStream()`, but you would need a rather large input set to get a benefit from parallel processing.

Note that this simple solution may do unnecessary work if you have a lot of non-matching phrases as it will create all substrings before checking whether they are contained in `wordSet`. A solution like [Flown’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50363405/2711488) will defer the creation of the substrings, so it can be skipped when encountering a word not contained in `wordSet` (also known as short-circuiting). Another performance improvement would be moving the creation of the `Pattern` out of the stream processing and re-using it (a `Pattern` is also created behind the scenes when using a method like `String.split` as in above solution).

```
Pattern whiteSpace = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
Predicate<String> inWordSet = wordSet::contains;
Set<String> resultSet = phraseSet.stream()
    .filter(phrase -> whiteSpace.splitAsStream(phrase).allMatch(inWordSet))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `equals` or `containsAll` method here.

```
Set<String> resultSet = phraseSet.stream()
           .filter(s->wordSet.equals(Stream.of(s.split("\\s"))//wordSet.containsAll(...)
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet())))
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```